# ES6: How to access instance class from static methods?

Tags: instance, static-methods, es6-class

What is the recommended way to access the instance of a class and its methods from, say a DOM button?
Consider this example:
Right now I am calling a static method of an ES6 class, because I don't know how to call the instance method:

```
<script src="MyClass.js">
<button onClick="MyClass.buttonClicked()">
```

The class looks like

```
   class MyClass() {
    
       static instance;
    
       constructor() {
         instance = this;
         //important initialization of some vars
       }
    
       static buttonClicked() {
          MyClass.instance.nonStaticButtonClicked();
       }
    
       nonStaticButtonClicked() {
         console.log("button clicked!");
         //use the vars which have been initialized in constructor()
       }
    
    }
```

This works flawless in Chrome and not at all in Safari, because apparently Safari doesn't like the static variable declaration and gives the error
"Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration.', see also the comment of Marthinus Engelbrecht here:
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration.' in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394980/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-expected-a-or-a-after-a-parameter-dec)

My question is, if what I do is wrong, how should I do it right?
In particular, what is the best approach to access an instance method from a button?

EDIT:
I was just overcomplicating things:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.myClass = new MyClass();
});
```

and the button:

```
<button onClick="window.myClass.nonStaticButtonClicked()">
```

No need for static calls and instances/singletons.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: `static` should work on Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static This looks right, as far as how to use a static class method.

Comment: It appears you misunderstand what a class is used for, what an instance of that class is and how to use it.  A static method is JUST a plain function that is named scoped to a class.  A static method does not use an instance of the class at all.  If you want to use a non-static method, you have to create an instance of the class by calling your constructor with `new`, save it somewhere and then use that instance to call a method as in `obj.method()` where `obj` is the instance of your class that you created and saved.

Comment: sleep furiously, I added the Safari error in question.

Comment: Thank you jfriend, but the question was: How do I access `obj.method()` from the DOM? Thanks for teaching me `new` though ;)

Comment: Check the next answer, scroll to the bottom answers to find the ones showing how to create a singleton class and call its methods without needing to use static, although you will find some examples using static too if this is your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you PerracoLabs, that was the right hint. I edited the question.